# BrightCove write Token requirement for Sitecore 7.1

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, brightcove, sitecore7.1

We have BrightCove Express version, and we dont have write token available. But in Sitecore when i add Brightcove account and there is write token field .

So is it possible to use Brightcove express with Sitecore 7.1 or we have upgrade our account.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The connector will still work without the write token; you will have a read-only connection to Brightcove.

The bigger issue is that your account needs access to the Brightcove Media API. If you're a Sitecore customer you should have that, but you should contact Brightcove to make sure that your account is configured correctly.